# Get name of class compile time like __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ and __LINE__

Tags: objective-c

Just like

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation MyClass

+ (void)helloWorld 
{
    printf("Hello world. The method being called is %s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [MyClass helloWorld];   
    }
}
```

Results in

```
Hello world. The method being called is +[MyClass helloWorld]
```

I would like to get just the class-name compile time.

Comment: `NSStringFromClass([self class])`?

Comment: That's not compile time, that's run time

Comment: you mean you want to get the name during the compilation phase of the build process? Where do you want to get it? If you look at the build transcript you will see each class being compiled one by one.

Comment: It's for an experiment within the class itself. I know there are other ways to reveal the name of a class. 1. xcode shows it to you. 2. runtime you can do `[self class]`. What I'm asking for is bluntly how to get it compile time accessible as a macro. Can we please stick to that?

Comment: There's no macro like this, see [this thread in objc-language list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2008/Aug/msg00166.html), there is a bug report for this.

Comment: why you can't use some custom C-function call in your macro to strip out class name from the __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ macro, like `StripForClassName(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)` ?

Comment: Because I need it at compile-time

Comment: _What I'm asking for is bluntly how to get it compile time accessible as a macro. Can we please stick to that?_ Yes, we can stick to that: the answer is that you can't unless you rewrite a little bit of the compiler to provide this otherwise unavailable macro.

Comment: @mah Thanks! A "no" followed up with what needs to be done is always appreciated! I don't think I will ever change the compiler, but it is good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard means of getting at a class name at compile time. Adding such nonstandard behavior would probably not be difficult but would require adding custom code to your compiler . Looking for where **FUNCTION** gets defined would likely be a good starting point.

When looking for a very specific type of solution such as in this case, it's generally best to mention up front the *problem* you're looking to solve, rather than defining terms of your desired solution.

The reason so many people comment about alternative solutions is that generally speaking, programmers are about providing solutions, not providing exactly what was asked for. We often find that what is being asked for is either impossible, impractical, or unlikely to be exactly what is wanted (and if all we ever did was provide what was asked for, we would waste even more of our time than we already do). When one of these conditions exists, we typically still look for a solution, just by changing the parameters a little. Hence in this case, while many people realize that a compile time determination is not available, many also probably believe there is no reason why a run time determination cannot satisfy the need. Of course there are some factors that could clearly dispute this, such as run time performance (unlikely to be a factor unless running on a slow CPU, and then use of ObjC at all comes into question) or memory overhead (same caveats).