# Macro for Objective-C class name at compile time, like __PRETTY FUNCTION__

Tags: objective-c, macros, compile-time

Is there any way to get the current class name via a compile time macro like `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`?

Perhaps `__CLASSNAME__`?

Comment: I'll ask anyway: What will you do with that? There probably is a solution for your needs, but it might depend on your usage.

Comment: There is no macro for class name see [QA1669](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1669/_index.html), and there is already a bug report for this [see](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2008/Aug/msg00166.html)

Comment: If you give some insight as to what you are trying to achieve someone might be able to provide a solution or workaround...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get name of class compile time like \_\_PRETTY\_FUNCTION\_\_ and \_\_LINE\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159317/get-name-of-class-compile-time-like-pretty-function-and-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I am aware of. However, when you follow the usual pattern of having one .h and .m file for each class, then you may find the `__FILE__` macro useful. See
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: Thanks, but would have to process this at compile time to just the class name.  Will see if we get this to go.

Comment: Going to accept this one, even though not 100%.  My need for this has gone away.  Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You want the name of a class or do I misunderstand?

Is

```
NSString *s =  NSStringFromClass([myInstance class]);
```

What you need?

Comment: This is *not* compile time, but runtime.

Comment: I honestly overlooked that part of the question. But isn't it so that at compile time, the class is not  necessarily defined?

Comment: I'd say it depends on what you are looking at. :)

Comment: Yes, need compile time.